# Images not loaded in UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uitableview

1. This is the function that repeats for every Cell in TableView. As you can see im passing  an array of images(called imageset) inside an object named Product.
   productImages is an array of Product. Inside this object we have Name, Price and imageSet.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductHomeCell

       cell.productName.text = productImages[indexPath.row].name
       cell.productPrice.text = "\(productImages[indexPath.row].price)"

       //cell.PageImages contains Array of Images
       cell.pageImages = productImages[indexPath.row].imageSet

       return cell
   }
   ```
2. Now we will se the Custom UITableViewCell where the information of the Product seen will be loaded and shown. Notice Im using a ScrollView to scroll through the images.(I took the code from a question in stackoverflow)
   PageImages is the variable that should have the imageSet passed.

   ```
   var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

   var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
   var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(60, 300, 195, 5))


   override func awakeFromNib() {


       super.awakeFromNib()
       scrollView.delegate = self
       pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(230, 14, 107, 37))

       //PageImages should be loaded.
       let pageCount = pageImages.count
       self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount
       configurePageControl()
       pageControl.enabled = false

       // 3
       for _ in 0..<pageCount {
           pageViews.append(nil)
       }

       // 4
       let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size


       scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
           height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)


       loadVisiblePages()

   }

   func loadPage(page: Int) {
       if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
           // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
           return
       }

       // 1
       if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
           // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
       } else {
           // 2
           var frame = scrollView.bounds
           frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
           frame.origin.y = 0.0

           // 3
           let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
           // let newPageView = UIImageView(image: imageC)

           newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
           newPageView.frame = frame
           scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

           // 4
           pageViews[page] = newPageView
       }
   }

   func loadVisiblePages() {
       // First, determine which page is currently visible
       let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
       let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

       // Work out which pages you want to load
       let firstPage = page - 1
       let lastPage = page + 1

       // Purge anything before the first page
       for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
           purgePage(index)
       }

       // Load pages in our range
       for index in firstPage...lastPage {
           loadPage(index)
       }

       // Purge anything after the last page
       for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
           purgePage(index)
       }
   }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       // Load the pages that are now on screen
       loadVisiblePages()
   }

   func purgePage(page: Int) {
       if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count{
           // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do         nothing
           return
       }

       // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
       if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
           pageView.removeFromSuperview()
           pageViews[page] = nil
       }
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }


   func configurePageControl() {

       self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
       self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

       self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
       self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       self.addSubview(pageControl)
   }

   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
       pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
   }
   ```
3. PROBLEM - The product name and price Load perfectly. The images dont. When i debug it looks like PageImages is empty when is awakeFromNib() is running, but when I debug in the cellForARowAtIndexPath method, the var PageImages is loaded with the imageSet at that indexPath.row.
   Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, No one is going to go through all this code. Can you please edit your code down to the relevant parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is executed before the cell is returned by `dequeue...`  So trying to set up your pages there isn't going to work.  The two approaches I've seen are to either have a  method to explicitly set up the cell:

```
func setupCell(productName:String, productPrice:Double, images:[UIImage]) {
    // Do most of what you have in awakeFromNib here
}
```

or to do it in the didSet for the property:

```
var pageImages : [UIImage] = [] {
    didSet {
        // Set up your page controller here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried with the didSet and worked just fine